# SFML Sprite not displaying for unknown reasons

Tags: c++, sfml

I do not know why but my sprite is not displaying. When i run the code i get no errors and i did a cout and it appears the function which calls setTextureRect on the sprite is getting called.

this is the call to the function the this pointer in this case refers to an Instance of the Player object

```
anim.playFrame(this, sf::IntRect(32, 0, 32, 32));
```

this is the function itself, Frame is just a typedef for sf::IntRect

```
void Animation::playFrame(IAnimatable* entity, Frame frame) {
    entity->sprite.setTextureRect(frame);
    std::cout << "new texture set" << std::endl;
}
```

In the game loop i called

```
Window.draw(player.sprite);
Window.display();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the white square problem. http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/graphics-sprite.php
is where you can find a solution(you might not though). This also happened to me, although I still have the problem.

Comment: mhm i can't really tell if this is the source of my problem, but can i send you the VS solution? it's a really simple program.